# instagram style explore page image list with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a instagram style explore page but i have one question here. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EyVjeQ?editors=1100)** from codepen.io .

In this demo you can see the images. The images `width` and `height` is different not a same. I want to crop that images with CSS Like this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YWyXOB)** page.

The difference between the first and second demo

First demo :

```
.exPex {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Second Demo:

```
.exPex {
   width: 200%;
}
```

So second demo working just in crome but this is not good idea i think. Anyone can tell me, How do I obtain the results of their second demo?

Comment: I think it's better to set height:100% as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the images up as background images and use `background-size: cover;` to get the effect that you're looking for ([DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXyVYV)). This has the downside that your users will not be able to right-click or drag the images (to save them, etc.) as they might be expecting to do.

HTML for an example image:

```
<div class="_jjzlb" style="background-image:url('http://mihangallery.ir/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Almost-Home-Wallpapers.jpg');">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
._jjzlb {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1px;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /* Optional centered background */
    background-position: center;
}
```

If this downside is not acceptable, you could also put hidden images on top of the backgrounds so that they will work like the user expects.

HTML for an example image with normal image mouse interactions:

```
<div class="_jjzlb" style="background-image: url('http://mihangallery.ir/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Almost-Home-Wallpapers.jpg');">
    <img src="http://mihangallery.ir/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Almost-Home-Wallpapers.jpg" class="exPex">
</div>
```

CSS to hide the image on top:

```
.exPex {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
}
```

And here is a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBvvxa) with the images, interacting with the user like you might expect them to.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @GCyrillus, there are downsides to using a background image rather than keeping the images in the content of the page. These might include search engines and screen readers failing to recognize the image. I do not have an exhaustive list of the downsides but depending on your application it may be worth investigating.

Comment: Nice answer i understood what i need to do. Thank you so much for it.

Comment: No problem @DevStud - Please note that after you made this comment I fixed a bug with the last CSS block that was causing the hidden images to not cover the full height of the squares.

Comment: yes i saw that before and i was fixed that also. Sometimes people do not think of simple solutions like me. :)

Answer (score 2):

you may use transform :

```
.exPex {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   min-width:100%;
   margin: 0;
   transform: scale(2);
   transform-origin: 0 40px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jrbPRy

Comment: If the image proportions are unfavourable (in this case since it's being scaled up to twice the size, "unfavourable" means the image is more than twice as wide as it is tall) and you're looking to fill a square, this will not fill the height of the square with the image.

Comment: @David actually, transforl:scale(2); reproduce the width:200% from its own demo without requiring twice space --- . but it keeps image in the content of the page, when in the background, it just turns to be designed and can be unseen for many reason and will never be there for screen readers and search engines. ;)  For me to advise to set content into css or background without explaining what it involves is not so wise.just my opinion ;)

Comment: fair enough, I appreciate you pointing it out. I do recognize that it does what the original demo does but I think that the question author is looking to have a grid of images that always look square regardless of the proportions of each original image. I realize there are drawbacks to my answer as well, but I tried to make it pretty clear that there are drawbacks. I will edit my answer to make this explicit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well it might seem obvious but you could just put a fixed width to it ? Try to change `width: 100%` with `width: 400px` on `.exPex` for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you define a dimension to the image the aspect ratio will also be included. The best way is to put your image inside a div and declare the size of images that way you will be able also to crop images.